# get image contained within object in fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

i have a canvas with several objects on it such as a rectangle. then i have images like in.bmp format that user can move around on the canvas and the images can be rotated as well.

what i need is the image if it is inside the rectangle. whT I HAVE tried is the .findObject method and get the object but how do i get the image data?

i need the image data so i can send to server for other downstream processing. any idea how this can be done in fabric?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this would help you
In my code, I use this to do something when I click on the object

```
canvas.fabric.on('object:selected', function(e) {
//make something 
 console.log(e.target._element);// this print  Image object Html in console
});
```